# How to create an integer or number from array of digits or string of digits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an integer or number that contains all the digits from an array of digits or string. How can I achieve that ?

for example:

```
digitArry = [9', '8', '7', '4', '5', '6'];
```

should become

```
integer = 987456;
```

Comment: `num = Number(digitArry.join(""));`

Comment: Already answered in [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/3441223)

Comment: What should be the result of `['95', '3']` or `['9', '000001']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `join` and `parseInt`:

```js
var digitArry = ['9', '8', '7', '4', '5', '6'];
var integer = parseInt(digitArry.join(''), 10);

console.log(integer);
```

EDIT: As suggested by @kay, another alternative is using `+` to convert string to number:

```js
var digitArry = ['9', '8', '7', '4', '5', '6'];
var integer = +digitArry.join('');

console.log(integer);
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but it's always a good idea to specify the radix in the parseInt method, even if base10 is the default.

Comment: Don't forget to pass `10` as the base

Comment: Make sure to specify the second parameter in `parseInt`, since some browser do not use the base 10 by default.

Comment: Never use `parseInt` without specifying the radix. Almost always `+str` is the better alternative.

Comment: @JeffNoel This has nothing to do with the browser. It's when the string starts with a `0`

Comment: Yes, edited the answer with the radix! + is simpler indeed

Comment: I don't see why the radix is necessary: `parseInt( "010" ) === 10 !== 8`.

Comment: Better to use Number(String) instead of parseInt